# Erro de divisão por zero

Tags: c

Sou iniciante em programação e eu tenho que montar um código em que eu coloco dois valores e o programa me passa o resultado em soma, subtração,multiplicação e divisão, porém ao dividir um numero por zero aparece uma mensagem de erro. Consegui fazer aparecer uma mensagem de erro caso seja dividido por zero, porém não consigo fazer outro tipo de divisão que não seja por zero.
Se alguem puder me esclarecer pois entendo pouco ainda de programação.

Esse é o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int num1, num2, soma, subtracao, multiplicacao, divisao;

  printf("Digite o primeiro numero:");
  scanf_s("%d", &num1);

  printf("Digite o segundo numero:");
  scanf_s("%d", &num2);

  soma = num1 + num2;
  subtracao = num1 - num2;
  multiplicacao = num1 * num2;
  divisao = num1 / num2;

  printf("A soma = %d\n", soma);
  printf("\n");
  printf("A subtracao = %d\n", subtracao);
  printf("\n");
  printf("A multiplicacao = %d\n", multiplicacao);
  printf("\n");
  printf("A divisao = %d\n", divisao);

  if (num2 != 0)
    divisao = num1 / num2;
  else
    printf("Invalido, nao pode ser divido por 0");

  printf("\n");

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isso aí não é C#, cara. Muito provavelmente não tem nada a ver com programação dinâmica também.

Answer (score 1):

A sua lógica para verificar se a variável num2 é igual a zero está certa, mas está sendo executada depois da divisão, seu código deveria ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
int num1, num2, soma, subtracao, multiplicacao, divisao;

printf("Digite o primeiro numero:");
scanf_s("%d", &num1);

printf("Digite o segundo numero:");
scanf_s("%d", &num2);



soma = num1 + num2;
subtracao = num1 - num2;
multiplicacao = num1 * num2;

divisao = -9999; //um valor estranho pra ser interpretado como um erro
if (num2 != 0)
    divisao = num1 / num2;
else
    printf("Invalido, nao pode ser divido por 0");

printf("A soma = %d\n", soma);
printf("\n");
printf("A subtracao = %d\n", subtracao);
printf("\n");
printf("A multiplicacao = %d\n", multiplicacao);
printf("\n");
printf("A divisao = %d\n", divisao);

system("pause");
return 0;
```

Lembre-se, sempre verifique algo que possa dar erro **antes** da execução.

Answer (score 1):

Só imprima o resultado da divisão se tal operação for possível.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num1, num2, soma, subtracao, multiplicacao, divisao;

    printf("Digite o primeiro numero:");
    scanf("%d", &num1);

    printf("Digite o segundo numero:");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    soma = num1 + num2;
    subtracao = num1 - num2;
    multiplicacao = num1 * num2;

    printf("A soma = %d\n\n", soma);
    printf("A subtracao = %d\n\n", subtracao);
    printf("A multiplicacao = %d\n\n", multiplicacao);

    if (num2 != 0) {
        divisao = num1 / num2;
        printf("A divisao = %d\n\n", divisao);
    }
    else
        printf("Invalido, nao pode ser divido por 0\n\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: consegui fazer desse jeito, deu certo o codigo obrigado quem ajudou xD